# Change gravity strength in sim nodes based on proximity to object

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

been bashing my head for a while, since I'm terrible with geo nodes logic.
I created instances of objects that are scattered on plane, and after that, they would fall into fluid, but since fluid does not interact with rigid bodies, and manually keyframing would be a bit of chore.

Main idea is to place proximty toggle object inside the domain, and when instanced object reaches "proximity area" it's speed would be reduced, essentially emulating being under water.
Here's my current setup, it's probably completely wrong, and maybe someone can explain what I did wrong

[image]

**Update:**

After some playing around and browsing few stackexchange threads, I found how to make it work, but here comes another problem, switch from one value to another changes instantly, while I want it to change gradually "sort of easing" I feel like vector curve could help with that, but I'm unsure where to put it

[image]

Blend file [image]

Comment: if u provide a blend file, i will help you - why? 1) because i am lazy 2) because you want help from us, who help for free in our spare time, right? -> so please make it as easy for us to help you. thx.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=VkYvQ1VJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VkYvQ1VJ/) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would work with geometry proximity. With the distance, you can control your speed.

I made an extra object for that proximity.

[image]

you can finetune the speed with the float curve.

result:

[image]

Note: i did not try to make a realistic "body falling into water" but i slowed it down a lot so that you can the how it is getting slower and that you can reproduce my solution.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing, thanks a lot, not sure why I overcomplicated it with too many nodes, but now I understand it a bit better. Thank you again!

Comment: thank you! you are welcome!